# Pointer to end of a function code

Tags: c, function, pointers, embedded

I understand that a function pointer points to the starting address of the code for a function. But is there any way to be able to point to the end of the code of a function as well?

Edit: Specifically on an embedded system with a single processor and no virtual memory. No optimisation too. A gcc compiler for our custom processor.

I wish to know the complete address range of my function.

Comment: There's no portable way to do this, but there might be compiler-specific tools to accomplish this.

Comment: Is this an academic question or do you want to solve a particular problem?  What you want to do sounds strange to me.

Comment: @5gon12eder: not an academic question, i want to know the code address range of a function.

Comment: @templatetypedef can you elaborate on compiler-specific tools, i dont want to see the addresses from the object code. Because by doing this I will have to keep on changing the addresses in my code whenever I make any changes to my code, which in effect would change the address range of the function I am interested in.

Comment: In most assembly-languages you can get the offset of the end of a function.

Comment: @fohsie I'm not actually aware of any compiler-specific tools to do this. From a language level, what you're doing would normally result in undefined behavior.

Comment: The pointer points to the beginning of the address, because the compiler needs to know its memory location before it gets executed and once its executed, it will be terminated so there is no need to reference terminal point.

Comment: There is no requirement that all the code for a function be contiguous. What do you plan on doing with this information? Maybe there's another way to solve your problem.

Comment: @RaymondChen : I m working on an embedded system with no virtual memory support, the function is contiguous in memory.

Comment: Why would you? For instance: would you like to *jump* to the end of a function?

Comment: @wildplasser : No, i just want to know the complete address range of function code.

Comment: But what are you going to do with that information? Are you doing it as part of stack walking? Are you going to memcpy the code somewhere? (And how do you know that gcc will keep the code contiguous?)

Comment: Maybe a detailed map file could help?  Ask your linker for one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put the function within its own special linker section, then your toolchain might provide a pointer to the end (and the beginning) of the linker section.  For example, with Green Hills Software (GHS) MULTI compiler I believe you can do something like this:

```
#pragma ghs section text=".mysection"
void MyFunction(void) { }
#pragma ghs section
```

That will tell the linker to locate the code for MyFunction in .mysection.  Then in your code you can declare the following pointers, which point to the beginning and end of the section.  The GHS linker provides the definitions automatically.

```
extern char __ghsbegin_mysection[];
extern char __ghsend_mysection[];
```

I don't know whether GCC supports similar functionality.

Comment: Thanks, I know this method, in gcc we can use the section attribute to place the code in a particular section and modify the linker script to get the end pointer.

But was looking for something portable. But as pointed out by others, it's not possible. So, I'll keep using this toolchain specific stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say why you need this information, but on some embedded system it's required to copy a single function from flash to ram in order to (re)program the flash.

Normally you are placing this functions into a new unique section and depending of your linker you can copy this section with pure C or with assembler to the new (RAM) location.

You also need to tell the linker that the code will run from another address than that it is placed in flash.

In a project the flash.c could look like

```
#pragma define_section pram_code "pram_code.text" RWX
#pragma section pram_code begin
uint16_t flash_command(uint16_t cmd, uint16_t *addr, uint16_t *data, uint16_t cnt)
{
 ...
}
#pragma section pram_code end
```

The linker command file looks like

```
.prog_in_p_flash_ROM : AT(Fpflash_mirror) {
    Fpram_start = .;
    # OBJECT(Fflash_command,flash.c)
    * (pram_code.text)
    . = ALIGN(2);

    # save data end and calculate data block size
    Fpram_end = .;
    Fpram_size = Fpram_end - Fpram_start;
} > .pRAM
```

But as others said, this is very toolchain specific

Answer (score 1):

In some implementations (including gcc) you could do something like this (but its not guaranteed and lots of implementation details could affect it):

```
int foo() { 
    printf("testing\n");
    return 7;
}

void foo_end() { }

int sizeof_foo() { 
    // assumes no code size optimizations across functions
    // function could be smaller than reported
    // reports size, not range
    return (int (*)())foo_end - foo;
}
```

Comment: You cannot subtract function pointers in standard C, only object pointers.  You also can't convert (cast) function pointers to object pointers or vice versa, though most compilers allow it.

Comment: It would be great if this is possible, i'll try it.

Comment: this may work with `-fno-toplevel-reorder` passed to gcc/g++

Answer (score 1):

There is no way with C to point to the end of a function.  A C compiler has a lot of latitude as to how it arranges the machine code it emits during compilation.  With various optimization settings, a C compiler may actually merge machine code intermingling the machine code of the various functions.

Since along with what ever the C compiler does there is also what is done by the linker as well as the loader as a part of linking the various compiled pieces of object code together and then loading the application which may also be using various kinds of shared libraries.

In the complex running environment of modern operating systems and modern development tool chains, unless the language provides a specific mechanism for doing something, it is prudent to not try to get fancy leaving yourself open to an application which suddenly stops working due to changes in the operating environment.

In most cases if you use a non-optimizing setting of the compiler with static linked libraries, the symbol map that most linkers provide will give you a good idea as to where functions begin and end.  However the only thing you can really depend on is knowing the address of the function entry points.